# How Geospatial data stored in Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, shapefile

I want to know how the geospatial data (e.g shapefile) stored in Orcle DB? In which format shapefile stored in Oracle DB ?

Is the shapefile is stored at any physical location let say c:\folder and then in Oracle DB we use some reference to this c:\folder path. is it like that ?

plz explain.

secondly, how we can retrieve shapefile from Oracle DB ?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is the Oracle Spatial User's Guide and Reference (at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/toc.htm for 10g Release 2).

The "built-in" functionality for spatial data involves storing the spatial data in the database itself using rows and columns like other kinds of data.  For example, you might have a CITIES table with "regular" columns like CITY_NAME and a "spatial" column (maybe named LOCATION) that contains the spatial representation of each city (maybe a point or polygon).  Oracle provides a special data type named SDO_GEOMETRY for storing spatial data in this way, along with functionality for indexing, searching, transforming, etc.  Oracle also provides utilities for converting shapefiles into this format.

There are two "levels" of spatial functionality -- the "basic" level (Oracle Locator) which is part of every edition (XE, Standard, Enterprise, etc.), and the "extended" level (Oracle Spatial) which is an additional cost option for the Enterprise Edition only.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I have one more question, can we import shapefile from stored spatial data of Oracle DB

Comment: I don't think Oracle itself provides functionality for converting from SDO_GEOMETRY to shapefile format.  However, ESRI ArcGIS has the capability to do this (it can read from SDO_GEOMETRY and write to a shapefile).  There are also third-party utilities with this functionality, like FME and the open-source GeoRaptor add-in for Oracle SQL Developer.  A good resource for future questions is the Oracle Spatial forum at http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=76.